# using Android, is there a significant performance hit to store small images as BLOBs in SQLite?

Tags: android

I have about fifty 10kb images that each have a text description and location coordinates.

I have two choices:

1. I can store the images as BLOBs
   in the SQLite db togather with the
   texts
2. I can store the images on SDRAM and
   store the path to the images in the
   DB

method (1) seems to be for convenience, but I wonder if there are any negatives to using this approach. For example, would the db respond slower ?

Comment: I found a pretty awesome tutorial for storing images as BLOBs and retrieving the images - just takes two lines each time:  http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for method #2 because the `kvPairs.put(FieldsLocation.IMAGE,       recloc.mImage);` in the code below results in a compilation error - which surprised me. I also tried `recloc.mImage.clone()`

```
public long insertLocation(RecordLocation recloc)
{
    Long lValueToReturn;

    ContentValues kvPairs = new ContentValues();
    kvPairs.put(FieldsLocation.LATITUDE,    recloc.mLat);
    kvPairs.put(FieldsLocation.LONGITUDE,   recloc.mLon);
    kvPairs.put(FieldsLocation.DESCRIPTION, recloc.mDescription);
    kvPairs.put(FieldsLocation.IMAGE,       recloc.mImage);

    lValueToReturn = mDB.insert(TABLE_NAME_LOCATIONS, null, kvPairs);

    return lValueToReturn;
}


public class RecordLocation
{
    public double mLat;
    public double mLon;
    public String mDescription;
    public Byte[] mImage;

    public RecordLocation()
    {
    }
}


final public class FieldsLocation
{
    //column names
    public static final String LOCATIONID = "_id";
    public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String IMAGE = "image";

    private FieldsLocation()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you declared mImage as **B** yte[] instead of **b** yte[] .

Comment: another good reason for using method #2 is that I can easily perform JSON -> SQLite conversion because I know I just need to cycle through string objects when the server sends me data. When that is done I'll loop through the data and kick-off threads to download the images.